# Windows cms синтаксис

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell, ос

Решил вникнуть глубже в команды и скрипты windows cmd/power shell. Существует ли в них свой определенный синтаксис, изучение которого облегчит восприятие инструмента в целом, или же каждый плагин/модуль имеет свою собственную структуру команд?

Comment: Да. Если про powershell - то тебе надо понять что такое ООП. Дальше будет проще.

Answer (score 1):

Если я всё правильно понял (из справки по командам можно узнать их синтаксис).

**PowerShell**:

- Полный список команд: `Get-Command -CommandType cmdlet`
- Справка по отдельной команде: `Get-Help <command>`

  1. Если не выводится справка: `Update-Help`
- Просмотр справки в Интернете: `Get-Help Write-Host -Online`

**Командная строка**:

- Полный список команд: `help`
- Справка по отдельной команде: `help <command>`